Get wifi working again after upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04. LTS
I have a Dell Inc. XPS 13 7390 notebook with Ubuntu from the year 2020 with an Intel Rivet Killer AX1650W Wireless
module supported by Linux and the following specs:
On older Ubuntu LTS the wireless worked but since I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS I can view but cannot connect to the SSID.
Further Info

My Network Adapter is detected by Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and I can connect to SSID in the BIOS.
My router should be OK, because other devices (Android, Windows 11) can connect. I can give further details if necessary.
After starting the notebook, I have no internet access through wireless and no internet access trough Ethernet. I need to run $ sudo dhcpcd to connect to the internet via Ethernet.

$ sudo dhcpcd 
[sudo] password for redacted: 
dhcpcd-10.0.6 starting
dev: loaded udev
DUID 00:01:00:01:2e:88:7d:2d:00:1f:b5:2e:73:36
Dropped protocol specifier '.link' from 'enx001fb52e7336.link'. Using 'enx001fb52e7336' (ifindex=2).
Dropped protocol specifier '.link' from 'wlp2s0.link'. Using 'wlp2s0' (ifindex=3).
no interfaces have a carrier


Immediately without internet access i get informed that software updates were installed, so there might be some loop?
Overview of installed firmware and system updates
details for system updates (actually downgrades (sic!)

It seems that my network interfaces were changed. Might that cause problems?
Outputof the Ubuntu Wireless Info script. Here are some outputs that might be useful:
lspci
$ sudo lspci -s 02:00.0 -v
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
Subsystem: Rivet Networks Wi-Fi 6 AX200
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18, IOMMU group 14
Memory at 9e200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=16 Masked-
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
Capabilities: [154] L1 PM Substates
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi

rfkill
$ rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
 1 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked

ifconfig
$ ifconfig
enx001fb52e7336: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.233  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 fe80::b9b6:f81:2077:d65b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:1f:b5:2e:73:36  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 32841  bytes 35186184 (35.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 12  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 16840  bytes 2410218 (2.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 9762  bytes 791882 (791.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9762  bytes 791882 (791.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether ac:67:5d:3c:47:4f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

iwconfig
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enx001fb52e7336  no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

nmcli
$ nmcli device
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION 
wlp2s0           wifi      disconnected  --         
enx001fb52e7336  ethernet  unmanaged     --         
lo               loopback  unmanaged     --         
p2p-dev-wlp2s0   wifi-p2p  unmanaged     --   

$ nmcli general status
STATE         CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN    
disconnected  none          enabled  enabled  missing  enabled

dmesg
$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[    5.709652] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.740388] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected crf-id 0x3617, cnv-id 0x100530 wfpm id 0x80000000
[    5.740562] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: PCI dev 2723/1653, rev=0x340, rfid=0x10a100
[    5.781118] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[    5.781641] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 77.ad46c98b.0 cc-a0-77.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.091629] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Killer(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX1650w 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (200D2W), REV=0x340
[    6.239772] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected RF HR B3, rfid=0x10a100
[    6.308239] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: ac:67:5d:3c:47:4f
[    6.427640] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    9.712060] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Registered PHC clock: iwlwifi-PTP, with index: 0

ip address
$ ip address show wlp2s0
3: wlp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:67:5d:3c:47:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

There are posts from others with similar issues, but I didn't find any solutions that worked for me.

I suspect the problem was switching to the consistent network configuration. Fixing this is beyond my skill level.
I solved it by doing a fresh install (deleting all previous configurations) of Ubuntu 24.04 and it worked.
